# Javascript : Can we use div instead of table in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I have a simple app in which I am showing a calendar for my users using full calendar API, but I would like to be user friendly in mobile, by default full calendar uses `TABLE`, now I Would like to use divs instead of the table so that I can easily manipulate the calendar.

Here is  [live demo](https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/rNVoeOd)

Here is my calendar

HTML

```
  <div id='calendar'></div>
```

Js

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var opts = {
        theme: true,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [{
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2016-01-01',
          end: '2016-01-04'
        }, {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2016-01-07'
        }]
      };


      $('#calendar').fullCalendar(opts);

    });
```

Is there any way to use divs instead of table in full calendar? any suggestion will be apreciated

Comment: The idea that `<table>` is not workable for small screen layouts is a strange one.

Comment: @Pointy I want something like this `https://i.ibb.co/Df17j8F/mobile.png` is it possible with tables ? in mobile device

Comment: I don't think fullCalendar's developers have spent much time considering the mobile use case, which is perhaps unfortunate. What's in your screenshot _could_ potentially be done with tables, or with divs too, but there's no support for it currently in fullCalendar. You'd be into the territory of a major re-write of one of the view plugins, to create your own custom one. Not a simple task. I'd say the most mobile-friendly view it supports currently is the "list" view. Maybe that should be your default when you detect a small viewport.

Comment: They also have a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) process if you want to try and get better mobile support prioritised.

Comment: @ADyson you wrote its possible using table then can you help me out on this? I tried but it looks so terrible I can't imagine putting that on production that is why I need help

Comment: @ADyson https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5322 I have requested a feature

Comment: Like I said, above, it's not a simple task. Far too much work for an answer here. Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js and then take a look at the source code of the "month" view plugin on fullCalendar's github page. Then you'll get an idea of the scale of the task. So no, I don't have time to help with that, really.

Comment: @ADyson is there any demo with a custom view out there so that I can see where to start?

Comment: I don't know of one personally (at least not for v4 anyway), you'd have to search around a bit online.

Comment: @ADyson understand I searched everywhere, bad news even full calendar themselves does not have example :( I will try to change the table using css and see what I will get

Comment: But the concept should be pretty much the same as the ones which come with fullCalendar - they're all implemented as plugins. That's why I suggested taking a look at the source code of the "month" view (otherwise known as "dayGrid") - it's probably a good idea to start by cloning that, and then gradually adapt it to your needs. Almost certainly easier than starting from scratch. In fact, if you read all the way to the bottom of the Custom Views page in the documentation (which I linked to above), it suggests doing exactly that.

Comment: Remember of course that if you do this, you also have an ongoing maintenance overhead, because you need to ensure your view stays compatible with fullCalendar itself, otherwise you'll be unable to upgrade, and end up missing out on features and bug fixes etc. They've already [started working on v5, and there are breaking changes](https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2020/02/changes-in-the-upcoming-v5) . In fact if you read the CSS changes description, it sounds like it would probably make it much friendlier to smaller screens anyway, or at least easier to customise in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for the link , check this calendar https://promo.com/tools/calendar/March is it possible to know which calendar are they using?

Comment: Press View Source in your browser and take a look through. I did so very briefly. There's a link to a Javascript file which points back to this website: https://www.calendarx.com/ . So they might be using that. I didn't look long enough to know if that's the only component. You can study the source code in more detail if you like.